# C# Roll back Streamreader 1 character

Tags: c#, project, streamreader

For a C# project i am using streamreader, i need to go back 1 character (basicly like undoing) and i need it to change so when you get the next character it is the same one as when you rolled back

For example

Hello There

we do

H

E

L

L

O

[whitespace]

T

H

E

R <-- we undo the R

so..

R <-- undid

R

E

that is a rough idea

Comment: i think it isn't possible as when you read a stream, it returns and advances, and that's gone. it is maybe possible with files and memory streams, but think of a network stream. you read the data, and it's incoming, it's processed and gone forever, it's not "stored" somewhere. but if you SPECIFICALLY want this for, e.g., memory streams, you may go unsafe code and do some pointer arithmetic and i *think* it should work..

Answer (score 2):

When you don't know if you want the value, instead of `Read()`, use [`Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx) - then you can check the value *without* advancing the stream. Another approach (that I use in some of my code) is to *encapsulate* the reader (or in my case, a `Stream`) in a class that has an internal buffer that lets you push values back. The buffer is always used first, making it easy to push values (or even: adjusted values) back into the stream without having to rewind it (which doesn't work for a number of streams).

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution would be to derive a class from StreamReader and override the Read() function.

For your requirements a simple `private int lastChar` would suffice to implement a Pushback() method. A more general solution would use a `Stack<char>` to allow unlimited pushbacks.

```
//untested, incomplete
class MyReader : StreamReader
{
    public MyReader(Stream strm)
        : base(strm)
    {
    }

    private int lastChar = -1;
    public override int Read()
    {
        int ch;

        if (lastChar >= 0)
        {
            ch = lastChar;
            lastChar = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            ch = base.Read();  // could be -1 
        }
        return ch;
    }

    public void PushBack(char ch)  // char, don't allow Pushback(-1)
    {
        if (lastChar >= 0) 
          throw new InvalidOperation("PushBack of more than 1 char");

        lastChar = ch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Minus one from the position:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("String");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //S
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //t
stream.Position -= 1;
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //t
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //r
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //i
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //n
Console.WriteLine((char)stream.ReadByte()); //g
```

Comment: For the StreamReader, access its BaseStream property and set its Position.

Comment: Not all streams have CanSeek() == true.

Comment: Bear in mind that the Position property is only supported by some stream implementations, e.g. NetworkStream *doesn't* support it. Use the stream's CanSeek property to determine if it's possible.

Comment: -1 for 3 reasons: a: byte != character, b: question was `StreamReader`, c: not all streams are seekable

Comment: @Ryan - also, re "access its BaseStream" - if you do that, you need to worry about the reader's buffer too - and again, not all streams are seekable (it is always best to avoid seek if possible)