# Read ClientHello before AuthenticateAsServer

Tags: c#, ssl, sni

I'm developing a Server Application that needs to manage different SSL services.
Each service has its own Certificate (with, of course, different CN).
I wanna use [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to provide the correct Certificate, but I'm struggling reading the ClientHello (where the SNI Extension is) before Authenticate the Stream.

That's the code:

```
byte[] ClientHello = new byte[3000];
Stream TargetStream = TargetTcpClient.GetStream();

//Whatever I write here let me be unable to successfully authenticate 
//If I don't read anything (like in this way), it works perfectly  
int ClientHelloN = 0; //TargetStream.ReadByte();// TargetStream.Read(ClientHello, 0, 3000);

/*SNI Logic to extract Server-name*/
Certificate = new X509Certificate2(/*PATH TO CORRECT CERTIFICATE*/);

SslStream SSLStream = new SslStream(TargetStream);
SSLStream.AuthenticateAsServer(Certificate);
```

If I directly Authenticate with a prefixed Certificate there's no problem, but when I try to read even just a byte from the Stream **before** authenticate, it loops forever in the AuthenticateAsServer method.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but why not peek the TcpClient's underlying Socket?

```
byte[] peekBuffer = new byte[16];
Socket socket = targetTcpClient.Client;
int bytesAvailable = socket.Receive(peekBuffer, SocketFlags.Peek);

if (bytesAvailable > 0)
{
    if (peekBuffer[0] == 0x16) // ClientHello?
    {
        SslStream secureStream = new SslStream(targetTcpClient.GetStream());

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I hadn't thought about just peeking the first byte to check it. Even if probably isn't perfectly reliable, it could work! I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Once you read data from `TargetStream` it's gone and your `SslStream` will be missing the beginning of the handshake.

I believe what you will need to do is wrap the `Stream` that you get from `TargetTcpClient.GetStream()` with your own `Stream` subclass.  In your subclass you can read bytes from the stream to parse the Client Hello, but you should save all those bytes in a buffer.  Your subclass should override [Stream.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) - when your override is called if there is anything in the buffer then return that, otherwise forward the call to the wrapped stream.  The approach is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7050430/1462337) except that subclasses `StreamReader` and only buffers a single char.

Comment: GreatIdea! Do you think that AuthenticateAsServer method will call the Read method for reading the ClientHello? I'll try asap

Comment: @Jamby It does appear from the documentation that any method of reading from a stream eventually calls the `Read()` function, so your override should be used.  Note that `Stream.Read()` takes different arguments from the `StreamReader.Read()` in the linked answer, plus you need to buffer more than one byte, but the basic concept is the same.  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, according to what Reflector says, SSLStream does not use `Read` method. I've proved that by simply override the `Read` method as well as the `ReadByte` and `BeginRead` ones, placing a breakpoint and it never hit the breakpoint when i call the `AuthenticateAsServer`

Comment: @Jamby That's not the behavior I see when I subclass Stream.  Try [this wrapper proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/rhashimoto/5929261).  That subclass just passes everything through and writes to the console on reads and writes; peeking into the bytes is still up to you.